# Kentico 9, hide document action buttons from webpart

Tags: button, action, kentico

i need to hide a Save, SpellCheck and Apply Workflow buttons or the full panel from a custom page.

On documents folder i add a transformation with custom control webpart, but on Page tab i need to hide the actions panel from webpart.

now, i can get a url on webpart init and from QueryString change parameter "showpanel" from 1 to 0. is there an API to access to that panel from webpart?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1m2B.png)

Answer (score 0):

i did this way, but i dont like this approach:

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    if (ViewMode == ViewModeEnum.Edit)
        if (QueryHelper.GetText("showpanel", "0") == "1")
        {
            string x = Request.RawUrl.Replace("showpanel=1", "showpanel=0");
            Response.RedirectPermanent(x, StopProcessing);
        }
}
```